# Is it possible to use multiple firebase projects on one flavor?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently using two projects (two apps) called **ABC app** and **123 app**. These two projects have two flavors. (dev environment - ABC DEV, 123 DEV firebase projects & live environment - ABC LIVE, 123 LIVE firebase projects).

Now I have to use ABC's firestore collection in the 123 apps. How do I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the Firestore service, you can declare and use a secondary Firebase app, as explained in the [FlutterFire doc](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/core/usage/#secondary-firebase-apps), letting you interchange the project the plugin uses.

---

There is also a doc section dedicated to "Using multiple projects in your application" in the Firebase doc, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application).

Answer (score 0):

A Firebase project defines the database that will be used by the associated apps.

So, given you seem to want to have a 'DEV' database (containing development data) and a separate 'LIVE' database (containing production data) - which is a common architecture - you need to create two Firebase projects one named eg. 'some suitable name'-DEV and the other named 'same suitable name'-LIVE. This gives you the data separation.

Then, you associate your ABC DEV flavor app and your 123 DEV flavor app with the 'xxx'-DEV project, and associate your ABC LIVE flavor app and your 123 LIVE flavor app with the 'xxx'-LIVE project.